# How to pass header in feign client especially HTTP Headers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I tried with Rest Template passing http headers and its working as expected but some how it not working with feign client.

Rest Client code:-

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders httpHeader = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeader.set("appsecret-proof", header);
HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeader);
String url = "https://localhost/groups/{pathVariable}/members/";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("pathVariable", pathVariable);
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                                                   .queryParam("token", token);
String uriBuilder = builder.build().toString();

ResponseEntity<MemberObject> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder, HttpMethod.POST, request,MemberObject.class, map);

MemberObject memberObject = null;
if (responseEntity != null && responseEntity.getBody() != null) {
    memberObject = responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

Fegin Client Code:-

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;

@PostMapping(value = "/groups/?token=xyz")
MemberObject getMemberGroup(@RequestHeader("appsecret-proof") String appsecretProof);
```

But fegin client giving an error as :

```
{"error":{"message":"Authentication credentials could not be found.","type":"Authentication Error","code":404,"sub_code":0}}.
```

Hardcoded the token in feign client still its giving an same error. It might be error with headers....any suggestion how to setup header in feign client.

Comment: `@RequestHeader` should work with spring cloud feign. Probably there might be a different error in your code. You got 404 error. Did you try to add request body parameter for your `getMemberGroup` method because it's POST, but doesn't have any request body.

Comment: Yes...doesn't have any request body...initally when  tried with resttemplate that time also i got the same error...then i realized that i putted wrong header datatype, i corrected the datatype of header then its working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

That's how you should structure the call if you're using Feign:

```
import feign.Headers;
import feign.Param;
import feign.RequestLine;
...
@RequestLine("POST /groups/?token={appSecretProof}")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
MemberObject getMemberGroup(@Param("appSecretProof") String appSecretProof);
```

In the above snippet the value of *appSecretProof* is substituted into the URL at execution time as the corresponding value of the *token*.